# How to fetch all issues from redmine application using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

here i am trying to fetch all issues from Redmine by using curl php below is the code which i used.

my CURL.php:
**flie class file in redmine/redmine_curl.php**

```
<?php # Redmine Api

class class_redmine{       
function get_upload_token($filecontent){
global $redmine_url , $redmine_key;
$upload_url = $redmine_url.'uploads.json?key='.$redmine_key;
$request['type'] = 'post';
$request['content_type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
//$filecontent = file_get_contents('test.php');         
return $token = $this->curl_redmine($upload_url,$request,$filecontent);
//$token->upload->token;
}
#Issue
function create_issue($post_data){
global $redmine_url , $redmine_key;
$issue_url = $redmine_url.'issues.json?key='.$redmine_key;
$request['type'] = 'post';
$request['content_type'] = 'application/json';
return $this->curl_redmine($issue_url,$request,$post_data);
}
function  get_issue($issue_id='',$project_id=''){
global $redmine_url , $redmine_key;
if($project_id!=''){
$issue_url = $redmine_url.'issues.json?key='.$redmine_key.'&project_id='.$project_id;
}else{ $issue_url = ($issue_id=='')?$redmine_url.'issues.json?key='.$redmine_key : $redmine_url.'issues/'.$issue_id.'.json?key='.$redmine_key;  
}
return $this->curl_redmine($issue_url,'','');
}
#Projects
function  get_projects($project_id=''){
global $redmine_url , $redmine_key;
$proj_url = ($project_id=='')?$redmine_url.'projects.json?key='.$redmine_key : $redmine_url.'projects/'.$project_id.'.json?key='.$redmine_key;          
return $this->curl_redmine($proj_url,'','');
}
#Curl
function curl_redmine($redmine_url,$request='',$post_data=''){
if(!isset($request['type'])){ $request['type']=null; }
if(!isset($request['content_type'])){ $request['content_type']=null; }
//Create a curl object
$ch = curl_init(); 
//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $redmine_url );
if($request['type'] == 'post'){ 
//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
//Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: '.$request['content_type'],                                                                               
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data))                                                                       
);  
}
//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
//if($postResult == false){ return $info = curl_getinfo($ch);}
$response   =   json_decode($postResult);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
return $response;
}

}//class_redmine

?>
```

here is my example.php

```
<?php
function get_redmine($methodName='',$data=''){
global $redmine_url , $redmine_key;

$redmine_url = 'http://192.168.12.231:80/';
$redmine_key = 'API KEY';
include_once('curlcall.php');
$obj_redmine    =   new class_redmine();

#check Auth
$res = $obj_redmine->get_projects();
if(!isset($res->projects) || (isset($res->total_count) && ($res->total_count)==0)){ return -1; }

switch($methodName){
case 'check_status' : return $login_integrate;
##check redmine integration in vision break;

##Project
case 'projectAll' : return $obj_redmine->get_projects(); #used
break;
case 'projectById' : return  $obj_redmine->get_projects($data['project_id']);
break;

##Issues
case 'issueAll' : return $obj_redmine->get_issue();
break;
case 'issueByProjectId' :  return $obj_redmine->get_issue('',$data['project_id']);
break;
case 'uploadFileToIssue' : return $obj_redmine->get_upload_token($data);
break;
default: return 0;
}
}

#get all issue
$res = get_redmine('issueAll');

echo '<pre>';print_r($res);
?>
```

This code is giving only 25 records.at the end of my output it is saying like
total:201
offset:0
limit:25
I can't understand how to get all issues please help anybody, i am new for php.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is all in [the API docs](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues), if you'd just bother to read it. use the limit parameter to get more results, and the offset parameter to load more

`/issues.json?offset=0&limit=100`  would fetch the first 100 issues

`/issues.json?offset=100&limit=100` would fetch the next 100 issues, and so on.

... but the first thing you should do is get your code formatted, because that unformatted thing is very annoying to read. then get rid of this line `'Content-Length: ' . strlen ( $post_data )` because curl will add that header automatically if you don't, and curl won't make any typos, nor will it calculate the length incorrectly, unlike us the progammers (curl has automated tests ran on every commit to make sure content-length is correct, i bet that's not part of your test suite), then get rid of this

```
if (! isset ( $request ['content_type'] )) {
    $request ['content_type'] = null;
}
```

because it should never be null. for future reference, if you literally have no idea what it's supposed to be, set it to `application/octet-stream`, but even that is wrong in this case, because the API docs says the only supported POST encodings are `application/json` and `application/xml`, so the correct thing to do here would be:

```
if (isset ( $request ['content_type'] ) && $request ['content_type'] !== 'application/json' && $request ['content_type'] !== 'application/xml') {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( 'invalid content-type specified. supported types are "application/json" and "application/xml"' );
}
if($request ['type'] === 'post' && !isset($request ['content_type'])){
    throw new \LogicException('no content-type was specified for this POST request, which is required. supported types are "application/json" and "application/xml"');
}
```

as for fetching all the issues, make a request first to see how many issues there are, then make a second request with limit=number_of_issues, like this

```
if (! $issue_id) {
    // first we check how many issues there are (OPTIMIZEME: there is probably a more efficient way to do this, for example limit=0 ?)
    $issues_url .= '&limit=1';
    $number_of_issues = $this->curl_redmine ( $issue_url, '', '' ) ['total_count'];
    $issue_url = substr ( $issues_url, 0, - 1 ) . $number_of_issues;
}
```

putting it all together, and you get this

```
<?php
// Redmine Api
class class_redmine {
    function get_upload_token($filecontent) {
        global $redmine_url, $redmine_key;
        $upload_url = $redmine_url . 'uploads.json?key=' . $redmine_key;
        $request ['type'] = 'post';
        $request ['content_type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
        // $filecontent = file_get_contents('test.php');
        return $token = $this->curl_redmine ( $upload_url, $request, $filecontent );
        // $token->upload->token;
    }
    // Issue
    function create_issue($post_data) {
        global $redmine_url, $redmine_key;
        $issue_url = $redmine_url . 'issues.json?key=' . $redmine_key;
        $request ['type'] = 'post';
        $request ['content_type'] = 'application/json';
        return $this->curl_redmine ( $issue_url, $request, $post_data );
    }
    function get_issue($issue_id = '', $project_id = '') {
        global $redmine_url, $redmine_key;
        if ($project_id != '') {
            $issue_url = $redmine_url . 'issues.json?key=' . $redmine_key . '&project_id=' . $project_id;
        } else {
            $issue_url = ($issue_id == '') ? $redmine_url . 'issues.json?key=' . $redmine_key : $redmine_url . 'issues/' . $issue_id . '.json?key=' . $redmine_key;
        }
        if (! $issue_id) {
            // first we check how many issues there are (OPTIMIZEME: there is probably a more efficient way to do this, for example limit=0 ?)
            $issues_url .= '&limit=1';
            $number_of_issues = $this->curl_redmine ( $issue_url, '', '' ) ['total_count'];
            $issue_url = substr ( $issues_url, 0, - 1 ) . $number_of_issues;
        }
        return $this->curl_redmine ( $issue_url, '', '' );
    }
    // Projects
    function get_projects($project_id = '') {
        global $redmine_url, $redmine_key;
        $proj_url = ($project_id == '') ? $redmine_url . 'projects.json?key=' . $redmine_key : $redmine_url . 'projects/' . $project_id . '.json?key=' . $redmine_key;
        return $this->curl_redmine ( $proj_url, '', '' );
    }
    // Curl
    function curl_redmine($redmine_url, $request = '', $post_data = '') {
        if (! isset ( $request ['type'] )) {
            $request ['type'] = null;
        }
        if (isset ( $request ['content_type'] ) && $request ['content_type'] !== 'application/json' && $request ['content_type'] !== 'application/xml') {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( 'invalid content-type specified. supported types are "application/json" and "application/xml"' );
        }
        if ($request ['type'] === 'post' && ! isset ( $request ['content_type'] )) {
            throw new \LogicException ( 'no content-type was specified for this POST request, which is required. supported types are "application/json" and "application/xml"' );
        }
        // Create a curl object
        $ch = curl_init ();
        // Set the useragent
        $agent = $_SERVER ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent );

        // Set the URL
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $redmine_url );
        if ($request ['type'] == 'post') {
            // This is a POST query
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            // Set the post data
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data );

            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
                    'Content-Type: ' . $request ['content_type'] 
            ) );
        }
        // We want the content after the query
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

        // Follow Location redirects
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

        /*
         * Set the cookie storing files
         * Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
         */

        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

        // Execute the action to login
        $postResult = curl_exec ( $ch );
        // if($postResult == false){ return $info = curl_getinfo($ch);}
        $response = json_decode ( $postResult );
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
        return $response;
    }
}//class_redmine
```

(which is completely untested on my part, by the way.)

another issue you should fix is that your curl code is executed completely without error detection. for example, curl_setopt returns bool(false) if there was a problem setting your option, and curl_exec() returns bool(false) if there was a problem with during the transfer, add error detection for that. these functions should make that rather easy:

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
function ecurl_exec ( /*resource*/$ch):bool{
    $ret=curl_exec($ch);
    if($ret===false){
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_exec() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return $ret;
}


function return_var_dump(/*...*/){
    $args = func_get_args ();
    ob_start ();
    call_user_func_array ( 'var_dump', $args );
    return ob_get_clean ();
}
```

and to be sure you're not leaking any memory, you can wrap it all around a `try{...curl...}finally{curl_close($ch);}`, making sure curl_close would always be called, regardless of which curl function throws an exception. (this prevents memory leaks)

Comment: Yes, it's there in the API, but i don't have clarity where should i use that in my code.please give me suggestion.